# Forms are broken in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, url-routing

I am trying to rewrite my urls to go from /controller/method to index.php?/controller/method, and that is mostly working, except that forms won't submit correctly. I have some routing set up, but the forms are also breaking on non re-routed urls. Here's a little context.

I have moved my index.php out into a separate web folder that is the web root, so there is no chance of exposing application files. I'm not sure whether this would potentially cause this problem, but it's something slightly unusual about my installation. My directory structure looks like:

```
+ codeigniter/
  + application/
    - models, views, etc
  + system/
  + web/
    - .htaccess
    - index.php
    - css, javascript, images, etc
```

My .htaccess is pretty simple:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

It seems to work fine on XAMPP for Windows, but it is broken on a basic Ubuntu LAMP stack. When I submit a form, nothing happens. The page that the form directs to loads, but as if the form hadn't been submitted.

Sorry, one more important piece of information: If I leave the index.php in there, so the urls look like `/index.php/contacts/edit/1`, it works.

Let me know if I can provide any more information. Thanks!

Comment: Describe "nothing happens" a little more.  Blank page? Errors on screen? Same page reloads in place?

Comment: @Michael edited. There's just not a lot that happens, or I'd be able to debug it more effectively. I was hoping that someone else had seen something similar. Error reporting is on, of course.

Comment: Not sure what's going on with the routing but what happens if you do a print_r($_POST) in the method to which the form is submitted?

Comment: Could show the form code please? Only `action="..."`

Comment: @theazureshadow, actually a lot does happen - plenty to identify the problem. Check your browser debugger (like Firebug) for HTTP redirects or status messages and check the server php log for PHP errors.

Comment: Also are you using the form_helper() or manually creating your forms?

Comment: I'm manually creating forms, e.g. `<form action="<?php echo site_url('yar');?>" method="post">`. The `$_POST` array is empty when I output it on the target page.

Comment: Have you tried base_url('my/path') instead?

Comment: In config.php `$config['index_page'] = '';` It's like this?

Comment: Put it in the answers section...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out a part of the .htaccess that I didn't include was causing the error to be difficult to find.

```
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

I had assumed that this would show a CodeIgniter error page if it reached that block, but it turns out (I assume) that CodeIgniter was valiantly trying to salvage the situation by looking at the path in `$_SERVER`, from which it was able to get the page it was supposed to display. However, since the path didn't exist, none of the $_POST data made it through. In the error log I was seeing this line:

```
[error] File does not exist: /path/to/web/contacts/edit/1
```

Enabling mod_rewrite solved the problem.